# Why does second asp.net mvc dropdownlistfor lose it's jquery mobile styling after successful data bind?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, ajax.beginform, dropdownlistfor

The webpage contains two asp.net mvc 4 dropdownlistfor controls. They are intended to be cascading drop downs where the selection of one drop down filters the values of the second drop down, using jquery mobile css.

When the page loads, the styling of each drop down is correct, using a jquery mobile theme.

I select an option from the first drop down and the onchange event fires jquery which submits the ajax request/form. I can hit a breakpoint in the mvc action which is gathering/filtering data to bind to the second drop down. And, the second dropdownlistfor binds without error.

However, it no longer has the jquery mobile theme/css styling. It appears like a plain html select list. Why?

```
//asp.net mvc 4 razor syntax
@using ( Ajax.BeginForm( "EmployeeExpense", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "selectEmployeeExpense" } ) )
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.EmployeeExpenseCategoryId, Model.EmployeeCategoriesDistinct, "Select Expense Category", new { id = "ddlEmployeeExpenseCategories", data_mini = "true", data_native_menu = "false" } )
}
@Html.Partial( "_EmployeeExpense" )

//jquery
$( "#ddlEmployeeExpenseCategories" ).change( function () {
$( "#ddlEmployeeExpenseCategories" ).closest( 'form' ).submit();

//c#
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EmployeeExpense()
{
  //get data for second drop down
  return PartialView( "_EmployeeExpense", model);
}

//_EmployeeExpense partial asp.net mvc view
@model Expense
@Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.EmployeeExpenseId, Model.EmployeeExpensesFiltered, "Select Expense", new { id = "ddlEmployeeExpenses", data_mini = "true", data_native_menu = "false" } )
```

Comment: `$("#selectID").selectmenu();` to create it.

Comment: @Omar, thanks for your help. I've looked at the jquery ui documentation, I don't understand the purpose of that method...can you explain why that may solve my problem?

Comment: This method is used when you create a `select` dynamically.

Comment: It worked. The only usage that made sense to me was to put that method in the onSuccess of the ajax.beginform and it worked.

Comment: Yup, you should call it once Ajax call is done. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

@Omar was correct. Placing that jquery ui `.selectmenu()` in a function on my external javascript file and calling that function using the onSuccess ajax attribute worked. Here is what I changed. Thank you Omar.

```
//asp.net mvc razor syntax
@using ( Ajax.BeginForm( "EmployeeExpense", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "selectEmployeeExpense", OnSuccess = "CreateSelectMenu" } ) )
  {
      @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.EmployeeExpenseCategoryId, Model.EmployeeCategoriesDistinct, "Select a Category", new { id = "ddlEmployeeExpenseCategories", data_mini = "true", data_native_menu = "false" } )
  }

//added js function with selectmenu jquery ui method to external js file
function CreateSelectMenu() {
  $( "#ddlEmployeeExpenses" ).selectmenu();
}
```